# (NSURLSessionDownloadTask cancelByProducingResumeData) crashes nsnetwork daemon iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

In my app user can cancel the download at any time. I cancel the download by calling `[task cancelByProducingResumeData:`. It works fine in most cases, however, it crashes the nsnetwork daemon if the download task is cancelled immediately after it is started/resumed. Here is a sample code that causes daemon to crash 100% on iOS 7.0. This issues doesn't happen on iOS 7.1!

```
NSURLSession *ses = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"aaa"] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *dTask = [ses downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
[dTask resume];

[ses getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {
    NSLog(@"%@", downloadTasks);
    if (downloadTasks.count>0)
    {
        for (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task in downloadTasks)
        {
            NSLog(@"cancelling : %@", task);
            [task cancelByProducingResumeData:^(NSData *resumeData) {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```

Here is the crash log:

```
Aug 13 16:15:06 Dev-iPhone backgroundTesting[4848] <Warning>: (
        "<__NSCFBackgroundDownloadTask: 0x1659cf80>"
    )
Aug 13 16:15:06 Dev-iPhone backgroundTesting[4848] <Warning>: cancelling : <__NSCFBackgroundDownloadTask: 0x1659cf80>
Aug 13 16:15:06 Dev-iPhone nsnetworkd[4827] <Error>: Property list invalid for format: 100 (property lists cannot contain NULL)
Aug 13 16:15:06 Dev-iPhone nsnetworkd[4827] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData)'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x2e469e8b 0x387636c7 0x2e3a4f9b 0x2e08b3d3 0x2e0ccee1 0x38c48103 0x38c4ce77 0x38c49f9b 0x38c4d751 0x38c4d9d1 0x38d77dff 0x38d77cc4)
Aug 13 16:15:06 Dev-iPhone ReportCrash[4849] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 4827
Aug 13 16:15:06 Dev-iPhone ReportCrash[4849] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process nsnetworkd[4827]
Aug 13 16:15:06 Dev-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.nsnetworkd[4827]) <Warning>: (com.apple.nsnetworkd) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
```

Is there a workaround to safely cancel the download without crashing the nsnetwork daemon? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the exception it feels like that the daemon could not generate resume data. Of course it's bug in iOS but what you could do as a workaround is to NOT allow to cancel unless you receive some bytes, in which case the daemon should be able to generate correct resume data.